# What is Shapely library alternative in R?

Tags: python, r, software-recommendations, shapely

I want to manipulate 2D geospatial geometries in R.

I am used to using Shapely in Python but I am a newbie in R.

Can you suggest Shapely alternatives for R?

Comment: There are probably lots in this list of Q&As about R and shapefiles: http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5br%5d%20shapefile or this shorter list about R and geometry: http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+geometry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[rgeos](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgeos/rgeos.pdf) is the R counterpart to Python's [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely). Both Shapely and rgeos are based on [GEOS](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/) (i.e. the PostGIS engine)